# Distinct() not working, behaving differently in .NET 5 and 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-5

I'm trying to trim duplicates in a list for a test app, and I'm using `Distinct()`.  I've implemented `IEquatable` on my object for the default comparer.  When I went to run it, it ended up trimming nothing at all from my list.  This happened enough times that I started to experiment and dig in a bit more.

What I've found is that something went seriously wrong with my code, and I'm not sure where.  In the below code I generate 1000 items with IDs between 0 and 9.  When I call `Distinct()` on my list, I expect to get a list of around 10 items.

What I get are wildly different results based on the version of .NET, both of which are pretty much dead wrong.

In .NET 5 the list isn't filtered at all.  1000 items before the call, 1000 items after.

In .NET 4.7.2, the list is filtered down to some number less than 10 -- usually around 2 or so in my attempts.  Given that there are 1000 items to be looked at, all with IDs in a 10-number range, I should get 10 pretty much every time.

So my question is, what's going on here?  I'm pretty sure I have a bug in my code, but I also can't explain the discrepancy between the two versions of .NET.

Here's the code, a pair of Fiddles, and output.

**Object Definition:**

```
public class Book : IEquatable<Book>
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Equals(Book other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode() ^ Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Main Program:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Book>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(GenerateRandomItem());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("List count: " + list.Count);
        list = list.Distinct().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Final list count: " + list.Count);
        foreach (var item in list) { Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.Id); }
    }
    
    private static Book GenerateRandomItem()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return new Book { Id = rng.Next(0, 10), Name = GenerateString(rng) };
    }

    private static string GenerateString(Random rng)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            result += (char)rng.Next(65, 91);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle .NET 5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9iL0Qt)
Output (due to `Random`, will differ each run):

```txt
List count: 1000
Final list count: 1000
Id: 1
Id: 0
Id: 2
Id: 3
Id: 4
... continues for all 1000 items ...
```

[Fiddle .NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9OdH6t)
Output (due to `Random`, will differ each run):

```txt
List count: 1000
Final list count: 1
Id: 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 Problems here:

1.You GetHashCode doesn't match the Equals. It should be only:

```
 public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

2.Also note that every time you do new Random() it is created using the clock. This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You should keep a single Random instance, as following:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    
    var list = new List<Book>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(GenerateRandomItem(rng));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("List count: " + list.Count);
    list = list.Distinct().ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Final list count: " + list.Count);
    foreach (var item in list) { Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.Id); }
}

private static Book GenerateRandomItem(Random rng)
{
    return new Book { Id = rng.Next(0, 10), Name = GenerateString(rng) };
}
```

Make these two changes, and you'll see both .NET 5 and .NET 4.7.2 work exactly the same.

Comment: Doesn't explain the difference between .NET framework and Core

Comment: When `Random()` doesn't generate different values, when seed is not also changed, the only explanation could be that they were created at same time (system Clock)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I had hoped it was something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm <strike>pretty</strike> sure that the reason can be found in the fact that you always create new `Random` instances very quickly in the loop. The .NET behavior of the [parameterless constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Random__ctor) is that it takes the current system time as seed. So if you call it quickly you will get the same seed again which means you will produce the same results over and over.

Instead you should pass the `Random` instance from `Main` to the `GenerateRandomItem` method.

This article here indicates that there was an (undocumented) breaking change in .NET Core. <strike>So maybe</strike> This is causing the difference:

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/3764

> The behaviour of the System.Random class in .NET Framework is that the
> parameterless constuctor takes the seed value from the current system
> time (Environment.TickCount). This has been documented here:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#instantiating-the-random-number-generator.
> This behaviour leads to the well-known issue: several random
> generators created in quick succession produce the same value
> sequences.
>
> The behaviour has changed in .NET Core: now the initial seed value is
> randomized as well, so several random generator's instances produce
> different sequences even if created in quick succession

A simple test with LinqPad 5(.NET Framework 4.6/4.7/4.8) vs LinqPad 5(.Net Core 3/ .NET 5) showed that it's the reason:

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        list.Add(RandomNumber());
    }
    
    var numLookup = list.ToLookup(i => i).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());
}

int RandomNumber()
{
    return new Random().Next(1, 100);
}
```

LinqPad 5(.NET Framework 4.6/4.7/4.8):
Always the same number

[image]

LinqPad 5(.Net Core 3/ .NET 5):
Different results even if using the parameterless constructor

[image]

---

As CloudWindMoonSun correctly pointed out your `GetHashCode` looks wrong, but it has nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in `HashCode` [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=net-5.0)

```
public class Book : IEquatable<Book>
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Equals(Book other)
    {
        return GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Id, Name)
    }
}
```